# how to make a http request in aws location service from postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services

i want get the geo-coordinated of an address. I've seen aws location official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/search-place-index-geocoding.html) , but i'm confused. I'm expecting to make a request with an address, and want to get the lat, lon of that address in response. How would i achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried calling the API? Looks to me like that is exactly how the API works, you get Results back which contains a Place which contains Geometry which contains coordinates.

Comment: yes, i tried. but didn't work .... actually i'm not able to make any api call .  this `https://places.geo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/places/v0/indexes/index_name/search/text` is my api endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wondering how to call the location api -

- Before calling the location(place api) api, you have create Cognito identity pool for accessing aws Location service. You'll get some data (access key, secrete key, session Token etc) in your `cognito-identity` api response.
- Then You need to create aws signature by combining all those data that you get from `cognito-identity` api response. In postman go to `Authorization` tab and select `AWS Signature` as type. This signature will worked as your authentication for you Location Api.
- Call Place api with your desire parameter.

  - Aws Location (in this case place api) api endpoint : `https://places.geo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/places/v0/indexes/index_name/search/place_name`
  - index_name : Name of your project
  - place_name : Name of The place

To Know more about place api visit [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location-places/latest/APIReference/API_SearchPlaceIndexForText.html)